# ScrollTop works when refreshing page, but not when I come from other link

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created a function which scrolls down a div `content` with overflow-y. 
This function works when I just refresh and scrolls correctly down to the bottom. When I come from a other page (same website) it does scroll, but not to the bottom, almost though.

I have used `console.log` to see how much it scrolls down and even there it shows that scrollHeight is bigger than the div itself, so that should be correct.

I've tried putting a `setTimeOut` around it with 3000ms, but that didn't work.

```
setTimeout (function () {
    $content.animate({ scrollTop: $content.prop("scrollHeight")}, "medium");
    console.log($content.prop("scrollHeight"));
}, 3000)
```

I don't think it's the code that is wrong, but something else. Anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

`animate` only works every time you open a tab

You should use [popstate event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/popstate):

```
function animate(){
  $content.animate({ scrollTop: $content.prop("scrollHeight")}, "medium");
  console.log($content.prop("scrollHeight"));
}
animate();
window.onpopstate = function() {
  animate();
};
```

Comment: Thnx for reply, but the behaviour remained the same. When I refresh it works perfectly, but when I use a link to go to there, it scrolls almost to the bottom.